# Use CSS in REACT

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

[image: Folder Structure]
How do i use css in react. Keeps throwing ./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve './app.css' in 'c:\Repo\ecom-front\src'. I know i'm doing something wrong so would like some help.
**ecom-front/src/core/Menu.js**

```
import React from "react";
import {Link, withRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import styles from "./app.css";

const Menu = () => (
 <div>
  <nav class="navbar">
       <span class="navbar-toggle" id="js-navbar-toggle">
           <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
       </span>
       <a href="#" class="logo">logo</a>
       <ul class="main-nav" id="js-menu">
           <li>
               <a href="#" class="nav-links">Home</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#" class="nav-links">Products</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#" class="nav-links">About Us</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#" class="nav-links">Contact Us</a>
           </li>
           <li>
               <a href="#" class="nav-links">Blog</a>
           </li>
       </ul>
   </nav>
  </div>
);

export default withRouter(Menu);
```

**ecom-front/public/index.html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
    // other code......
  </head>
```

**ecom-front/src/user/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './Routes';
import './app.css';
```

**ecom-front/src/core/app.css**

```
{
            box-sizing: border-box;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        body {
            font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
        }

        .navbar {
            font-size: 18px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, #2376ae 0%, #c16ecf 100%);
            border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .main-nav {
            list-style-type: none;
            display: none;
        }

        .nav-links,
        .logo {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
        }

        .main-nav li {
            text-align: center;
            margin: 15px auto;
        }

        .logo {
            display: inline-block;
            font-size: 22px;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 20px;
        }

        .navbar-toggle {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            right: 20px;
            cursor: pointer;
            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
            font-size: 24px;
        }

        .active {
            display: block;
        }

        @media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
            .navbar {
                display: flex;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding-bottom: 0;
                height: 70px;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .main-nav {
                display: flex;
                margin-right: 30px;
                flex-direction: row;
                justify-content: flex-end;
            }

            .main-nav li {
                margin: 0;
            }

            .nav-links {
                margin-left: 40px;
            }

            .logo {
                margin-top: 0;
            }

            .navbar-toggle {
                display: none;
            }

            .logo:hover,
            .nav-links:hover {
                color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
            }
        }
```

So i tried a lot of different ways to put an external css file, as i am trying to use flexbox or not be dependant on bootstrap. I do not know if i should install an npm package or if i am missing something as i only know the traditional way to implement css just not with REACT.

Comment: Can you share your folder structure?

Comment: i added the photo

Answer (score 2):

You are importing the css file incorrectly.

Instead of

`import styles from "./app.css";`

Do this

```
import "./app.css";
```

There is no styles being exported from css file. And use className at place of 
class

```
<div className="class">Get work done in over 1450 different categories</div>
```

EDIT: It's because the path you are importing the css from in your `ecom-front/src/index.js` is wrong

It should be

```
import './core/app.css';
```

Comment: @Omar Okay can you share the folder structure ? And does doing this gives the same error?

Comment: I added the photo above and it keeps giving me different errors each time

Answer (score 1):

You need not link it in the  section.

Also, use 'className' (case-sensitive) in place of 'class' and if you want to apply class 'some_class' use the syntax

```
className={ styles.some_class }
```